# Python add exception to function

Tags: python, function, for-loop, if-statement

I have writte the following function:

```
List=[1, 2, 3, 4]
def get_choice(DF4, column1):
    m = {}
    for v in DF4[column1].unique():
        m[v] = input('Label for {} ='.format(v))
        if m[v] not in List:
            print("Incorrect input. Use 1, 2, 3, or 4")
            m[v] = input('Label for{} ='.format(v))
    DF4['Label'] = DF4[column1].map(m)

    return DF4
```

This function asks me to create an input for each row from a column. However, what I would like to do is skip the input for a few rows based on the value of another column, say column 2.

Is there a way I can add this to my function? So say for example, if the value in column 2 == 10, I will not have to give input for that row.

Comment: `if value-in-column2 != 10: input()`?

Comment: Where would I add this to the function?

Comment: just where your input is. so it gets conditioned by the value of the second column

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work unfortunately

Comment: First of be careful with your comparison with the input value as input yields you a string value and your list only contains ints.